# how can i change the cursor speed of an external mouse?

Tags: touchpad, cursor

I have a laptop connected to a tv and I use a logitech k400 keyboard with a touchpad.

When i move the cursor with the external touchpad its rather slow and i would like to make it faster.

I have already tried going to System Settings>Mouse and Touchpad and changed the pointer speed, however it does not effect my external touchpad.

changing the pointer speed does effect the touchpad that is built into my laptop.

is there a way to make the cursor move faster with my external touchpad?